# Get variable and save it inside the same php file?

Tags: php, variables, save

I tried doing this

```
<h1>My Css Colors</h1>
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="csscolor"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<div ID="csscolors">
</ul>
<?php
    $csscolor = $_GET['csscolor'];
    echo '<li>'. $csscolor .'</li>'; // I used `echo` b/c I don't know anything else
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

How do I save that `<li>some csscolor</li>` on that same php file and so that I could add as many `li` as I want?

Comment: Define:"Save file".  What you probably want to do is add it to a database.

Comment: @SomeKittens I am total null in php. Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Or maybe store the values in a cookie/session.

Comment: install WAMP/XAMPP/MAMP at your computer first inside its root folder save your file as myfilename.php (pph extension) run it in browser ..localhost/myfilename.php and see the output then

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to save a value, your best bet is to put in in a database, rather than try and hardcode it into the PHP file (especially if you want to add more `<li>`.  Use the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) classes to communicate with your database.  I'd recommend getting XAMPP/WAMP to experiment on your home machine.

Answer (score 1):

See if you are having more than one css classes that you need to maintain between some pages and being used again and again then as @SomeKittens, mentioned you can store these values to the database but if your application does not have so many database tradeoffs than you can store it to the CONSTANT variable like

```
define('CSSCOLOR', '#EFEFEF'); \\ Or any color code you want to put in second parameter.
```

Then put this code in one global file and where you want to use this code at that include that file in where you want to use this constant you can use it like

```
echo '<li>'. CSSCOLOR .'</li>';
```

Another way you can store it to session or cookies as mentioned by hidemaru
fist at time of login or some global include file say in global.php

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['color'] = "#DEFDEF"; // any of your color code here
```

and in file where you want to use say index.php

```
session_start(); 
echo '<li>'. $_SESSION['color'] .'</li>';
```

Hope you have got it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use **cookies or session** to store all the CSS colors.

Below is sample code using ***$SESSION***.

```
<?php 
   // this starts the session 
   session_start(); 

   // get all CSS colors in SESSION
   $allCssColors=$_SESSION['color'];
   if (!isset($allCssColors)) {
      $allCssColors=array();
   }
   $allCssColors[count($allCssColors)]=$_GET['csscolor']; // add the new one

   // now display all the CSS colors
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($allCssColors); ++$i) {
      print '<li>'.$allCssColors[$i].'</li>'
   } 
   $_SESSION['color'] = $allCssColors; // save all CSS colors in SESSION

?>
```

Comment: Thnx for helping me out, but how do you make it independent from browser cookies?

Comment: Well in that case, you will use **URL Rewriting**. URLRewriting can be used in place where we don't want to use cookies. It is used to maintain the session.